# Regex for replace newlines after last symbol occurence in multiline mode

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

Payload (multiline text file);

```
foo bar () )
zab()rab)(oof
)
abc
dfe;

aaa )bbb
()hhh(
)
xxx
yyy;
```

Expected result (after `preg_replace()` call or analog):

```
foo bar () )
zab()rab)(oof
) abc dfe;

aaa )bbb
()hhh(
) xxx yyy;
```

So, I need a regex that do next: find latest `)` symbol before `;` and replace all space symbols (`\s` in terms of regexp) between `)` and `;` to the end of file.

I try to play with negative lookbehind but no luck in multiline mode.

Comment: to replace it with what?

Comment: `$payload = preg_replace_callback('~\)([^\)\;]+)\;~', function($matches){ return ')' . preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', $matches[1]) . ';';}, $payload);`

Comment: @Luke replace with empty string.

Comment: @Deadooshka thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this comment to flag question as answered: look at Deadooshka`s comment.

Answer (score 0):

if the replacement does not have to be with pure regexp i would use regexp just for the matching.

`\)([^\)]+);`

this ensures that it takes the latest `)` before `;`.

after that you would have the contents whats in between and there you could just replace the \n and \r or whatever you want with what ever you want.